# possible memory leak in charting toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, wpf-controls

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Interval="{Binding BGModelInstance.Interval}"
                                Minimum="{Binding BGModelInstance.MinValue}"
                                Maximum="{Binding BGModelInstance.MaxValue}"
                                Title="" TitleStyle="{StaticResource GraphDataVisualNoTitleStyle}"
                                ShowGridLines="True"
                                GridLineStyle="{StaticResource GraphTickerLineStyle}"
                                MajorTickMarkStyle="{StaticResource GraphTickerLineStyle}"
                                AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource NumericAxisLabelStyle2}" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
```

Problematic area is binding interval with decimal value, so that we can change dynamically.
This piece of code works fine in most of the cases, except when interval changes from huge value(500000000000) to very little value(0.25), I'm seeing huge memory leak in charting toolkit. 
Can someone suggest me to simplify this area or alternate method to bind Interval?

Additional info: we are using very simple styles.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As I didnt get any help from any forum.
I simplified logic around it, using a multiplier. So, there will not be this many intervals freeing, in case of rapid downgrade. hence problem gets solved. 
And i binded UI with another variables with actual large number.

Hope this helps someone.